How can I improve this approach for natural background extension in an image using OpenCV?
I'm working on expanding the background of an image using OpenCV in Python. My current approach involves replicating the border and applying a Gaussian blur to the extended areas to blend them into the original image. The goal is to make the background extension look more natural, especially for images with consistent textures.
Here's the code I'm currently using:
import cv2
import numpy as np

def expand_image_with_smart_blend(image_path, top=50, bottom=50, left=50, right=50):
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    original_h, original_w = img.shape[:2]

    expanded_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, top, bottom, left, right, cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
    
    blurred_img = expanded_img.copy()

    if top > 0:
        blurred_img[0:top, :] = cv2.GaussianBlur(expanded_img[0:top, :], (51, 51), 0)
    
    if bottom > 0:
        blurred_img[original_h + top:original_h + top + bottom, :] = cv2.GaussianBlur(expanded_img[original_h + top:original_h + top + bottom, :], (51, 51), 0)
    
    if left > 0:
        blurred_img[:, 0:left] = cv2.GaussianBlur(expanded_img[:, 0:left], (51, 51), 0)
    
    if right > 0:
        blurred_img[:, original_w + left:original_w + left + right] = cv2.GaussianBlur(expanded_img[:, original_w + left:original_w + left + right], (51, 51), 0)

    cv2.namedWindow("Smart Blended Expanded Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.namedWindow("Orig Image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imwrite('expanded_smart_blended_image.jpg', blurred_img)
    cv2.imshow('Smart Blended Expanded Image', blurred_img)
    cv2.imshow("Orig Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


expand_image_with_smart_blend('test_img.jpg', top=100, bottom=100, left=100, right=100)

What I've tried:
cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE: I use this to replicate the edges of the original image into the newly expanded areas.
Gaussian blur: Applied to the expanded regions to soften the transitions between the original image and the new areas.
The issue:
The results are somewhat acceptable, but the transitions still don't look as natural as I'd like. In particular:
Over-blurring in some areas makes the background look unrealistic.
The replication of the edges doesn't always work well for images with more complex textures.
Original Image Result Image
Question:
Is there a more sophisticated approach to expanding the background of an image in OpenCV or other libraries that would give more natural, seamless results? I'm open to approaches involving advanced image processing techniques or machine learning. Any approach with Diffusion Models would also work.

you can't expect better from content-unaware approaches. the next level up involves AI.

I've tried a few diffusion models as well, but all of them don't work the way I want. They try to paste the original image into the padded area. Do you know any Diffusers I can use for this case?

Please show or explain what you expect that is better than what you have.

I used this model and logic to get better image expansion results:
image_data = await image.read()
        image_stream = BytesIO(image_data)
        img = Image.open(image_stream)
        
        processor = BlipProcessor.from_pretrained("Salesforce/blip-image-captioning-large")
        model = BlipForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("Salesforce/blip-image-captioning-large")
        pipe = StableDiffusionInpaintPipeline.from_pretrained(
            "benjamin-paine/stable-diffusion-v1-5-inpainting",
            variant="fp16",
            torch_dtype=torch.float16,
        ).to("cuda")

        inputs = processor(img, return_tensors='pt')
        out = model.generate(**inputs)
        prompt = processor.decode(out[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
        image = np.array(img)
        height, width = image.shape[:2]
        padding = 100
        mask = np.ones((height+2*padding, width+2*padding), dtype=np.uint8) * 255
        mask[padding:-padding, padding:-padding] = 0

        image_extended = np.pad(image, ((padding, padding), (padding, padding), (0, 0)), mode='constant', constant_values=128)
        init_image = Image.fromarray(image_extended).convert("RGB")
        mask_image = Image.fromarray(mask).convert("RGB")

        image = pipe(prompt=prompt, image=init_image, mask_image=mask_image).images[0]

Main issue was of transitions and by this model's use, there were no transitions.
